# How to change the Button text with the android keyboard?

Tags: android, button, text, input, android-softkeyboard

I created a button in my xml (normal button) with text set to "0".
I attached an OnClickListner to it, and I got the keyboard to show using this code:

```
public void Measure(View paramView) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

Now I want the text in the button to change when I write something using the popped up keyboard.
I want to fill it with numbers - example 13.45.

I don't want to change the button to an editText.

Anyone got an idea how to do this?
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance for all the replies.

Comment: please look my answer below please, if I dont understand your question correctly please warn me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using button use an edit text and change the background of the edittext to make it look like a button

Comment: Do you think this is the best way to do it?

Comment: @RafaelSkubisz Yes since you want to get user input you can use an editText and by setting a click listener for the same you can get the click events.

Comment: Thx. I'll try doing it your way, to bad there is no way to do it using buttons. How to set the background to the default button look?

Comment: For everyone that wants to know how to set the button background to the default_button tou need to enter the folder android-sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable and find there btn_default_holo_dark or light copy it to your project and then copy the needed png files from res\drawable-hdpi etc. Thanks for the help pvn

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
      final  Button mbutton=(Button)android.findViewById(R.id.m_button_id); 
         mbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {   
                mbutton.setText(12+"");
                //or mbutton.setText("12");
            }
         });
```

Comment: I don't want it to set the text OnClick. OnClick I open the android keyboard, using the keyboard I write "12.3456" and now I want the number written using the keyboard to show up as the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this through XML by specifying a button's android:inputType="text" like so

in MainActivity.java:

```
final Button editableButton = findViewById(R.id.editableButton);
```

in activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/editableButton"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="text"
 android:text="Button1" />
```

I have not figured out how to do this by Java alone. Using

`button.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)`
does not work, even though it feels like it should =(